# javascript alt/fancy text generation

Tags: javascript, unicode, ascii

I am trying to understand how alt text/fancy text generation works.

When I say alt text/fancy text, I mean: text like:   [(Source)](https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html)

I've been searching for 40 minutes but I can't find anything on this. I am trying to make something in JavaScript, but I don't even know how to start because I don't understand how it is being generated.

I want to make a make a website which allows you to convert normal ASCII characters into cool/fancy text. Doing this, using JavaScript text generate these cool/fancy texts.

1. User types `example text` into the input box, as they are typing...
2. Using JavaScript it converts it in real time to

So as soon as the user types `e` it starts to convert it `e`.

I am trying to make my own version of [coolsymbol](https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html)

Comment: What are you trying to make, could you be more precise ?

Comment: @jo_va Edited my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those special characters are actually each composed of *two* code points: `55349` and something else, `56658` and above (the second code point varies for each character).

```js
const str = '';
console.log(str.charCodeAt(0), str.charCodeAt(1));
```

You can use a regular expression to replace each character in the input with a string composed of the `55349` code point, plus the code point related to the character in question:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  output.textContent = input.value.replace(/[a-z]/g, (char) => {
    // make code indexed from 0 to 25, corresponding to a to z:
    const code = char.charCodeAt() - 97;
    // add the above to 56658, since 56658 represents :
    return String.fromCharCode(55349, code + 56658);
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="input" value="example text">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I have a couple questions. 1. When you say code points, do you mean like the decimal value? Like I know, if you add 32 to, do `A`'s decimal value, you get lower case 'a'. Is it something similar? 2. How did you determine there were 2 code points? And not 3 or 4 code points? I'm a complete noob at this. Also I think your javascript doesn't run properly.

Comment: Just see the first snippet for an example of what I did - I noticed that `''.length === 2` and then checked code points for different possible characters. I saw that the first code point was always the same (55349) and the second point was directly related to the index of the character (0 for a, 25 for z). So, just get the index of the *normal* `a-z` character and add it to the second code point for ``, and you have a working script.

Comment: The snippet works just fine for me. Just type text into the input and blur it, and you'll see the result in the output.

Comment: @CertainPerformance maybe listen to `keypress` event for the demo?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes it worked for me now. Thank you for explaining, I will see if I can try making this myself

Comment: If you don't want to worry about the actual values of characters, you can use [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) and [fromCodePoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint) instead of *charCodeAt* and *fromCharCode*: `const index = char.codePointAt() - 'a'.codePointAt(); return String.fromCodePoint(''.codePointAt() + index);`

Comment: Note that for capitals, a few of them do not conform to a similar pattern, eg. capital C is not `''`, but `'ℂ'` (U+2102).