# Generate fancy/alt text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unicode

I'm curious as to how one would build a webpage that allows you to input text and dynamically display it in different styles with javascript.

Much like: `ρ૨εѵเεω ƭεאƭ` [(Source)](https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html)

Edit: found this [(SO Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54719156/javascript-alt-fancy-text-generation)

```js
function Demo() {

    const style1 = {
        'a' : '',
        'b' : '',
        'c' : '',
        'd' : '',
    };

    const style2 = {
        'a' : '',
        'b' : '',
        'c' : '',
        'd' : '',
    };

    function strtr(s, p, r) {
        return !!s && {
            2: function () {
                for (var i in p) {
                    s = strtr(s, i, p[i]);
                }
                return s;
            },
            3: function () {
                return s.replace(RegExp(p, 'g'), r);
            },
            0: function () {
                return;
            }
        }[arguments.length]();
    }

    const input = document.querySelector('#input');
    const style = style1; // Text style
    let outputt = strtr(input, style);
    console.log(outputt);


  return (
        <div>
          <Form>
            <Form.Item>
              <Input id="input" placeholder="input text" />
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
        </div>

      <div>
        <p>Style One:</p>
        <Form>
            <Form.Item>
              <Input size="large" id="output"/>
            </Form.Item>
          </Form>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

But I the output doesn't render in the form. Making some progress nonetheless

Comment: If you are practicing, why don't you start with something, that doesn't make you stumble, before even properly having started? It doesn't sound like a good practice task.

Comment: now im even more curious as to how this would be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an array of letters with different styles (in any programming language, here we're going to use Javascript).

> The styles need to be extended and add more..., I've only tried to give you an example of it.

```js
const style1 = {
    'a' : '',
    'b' : '',
    'c' : '',
    'd' : '',
};
const style2 = {
    'a' : '',
    'b' : '',
    'c' : '',
    'd' : '',
};

function strtr(s, p, r) {
    return !!s && {
        2: function () {
            for (var i in p) {
                s = strtr(s, i, p[i]);
            }
            return s;
        },
        3: function () {
            return s.replace(RegExp(p, 'g'), r);
        },
        0: function () {
            return;
        }
    }[arguments.length]();
}

const str = 'abc'; // Text
const style = style1; // Text style
let output = strtr(str, style);
console.log(output);
```

**Update**

Within the class in the `contructor()` method we need to define our state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {output: ""};
}
```

Also in the JSX:

```
<p>Style One:</p>
<div>{this.state.output}</div>
```

Finally in the `addEventListener`'s callback:

```
this.setState({output: String.fromCharCode(55349, code + 56658)});
```

Comment: I'm hoping someone can checkout my edit and help shed some light

Comment: haha personally liked your solution more but implementing it with states for dynamic effect is where I currently am. would be even best to display it within the output form instead of the div. edited the question just after you edited your answer